# Parent Category Always null in Entity Framework lazy load mode

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading

It loads category but always with null parent. I want get hierarchy category with given ID.

```
public static Category GetCategory(System.Guid ID, ActionLinkInfo AInfo)
        {
            Category category = null;

            using (TIKSN.STOZE.Data.StozeContext DContext = new Data.StozeContext())
            {
                var cats = from cat in DContext.Categories where cat.ID == ID select cat;

                foreach (Data.Category Cat in cats)
                {
                    category = new Category(Cat, Cat.Parent == null ? null : GetCategory(Cat.Parent.ID, AInfo), AInfo);
                }
            }

            return category;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var cats = from cat in DContext.Categories.Include("Parent") where cat.ID == ID select cat;
```

Or you can change your model, to include that `ParentID` as an integer in `Category` class:

```
public class Category {

    /* (...) */

    public int ParentID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentID")]
    public Category Parent { get; set; }
}
```

With that you'll be able to get `Cat.ParentID` without loading whole `Parent` object from database.

Comment: But this is not lazy load. This is eager load.

Answer (score 0):

The solution were to explicitly ask for loading a parent.

```
public static Data.Entity.Category GetCategory(long ID)
    {
        Data.Entity.Category category;

        using (Data.StozeContext DContext = new Data.StozeContext())
        {
            var categories = from SingleCategory in DContext.Categories.Include("Parent") where SingleCategory.ID == ID select SingleCategory;

            category = categories.Single();
        }

        return category;
    }
```